# How to populate choice form from db in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I can't figure out how to populate `choice form` from `db`. I know about `ModelChoiceForm` but the problem seems to be slightly different.

I want `user` to choose which sector does he work in. For example: 'Finance','Electronics' etc. which I would do simple:

```
SECTOR_CHOICES = (('finance',_('Finance'),
                   'electronics',_('Electronics')...
                 ))
```

But the problem is that I want `admin` of the web to be able to add new choices, remove choice etc.

What came to my mind is to create a simple `Model` called `Sector`:

```
class Sector(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

and `User` would have new attribute `sector = models.ModelChoice(Sector)`.

But I'm scared what would happend when `admin` changes or removes a sector which is already used, and more, what if he removes it and the `sector` attribute is required?

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just override the delete_model as custom action and there check if the selected sector object is in use.

```
def delete_model(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        if UserModel.objects.filter(sector=obj).exists():
            # do not delete, just add some message warning the admin about it
        else:
            obj.delete()

class UserModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [delete_model]
    # ...
```